# Simulate pack('J') in php < 5.6

Tags: php, pack, php-5.5

I would need `pack('J', $val)` in php 5.5 but 'J' is supported in 5.6 onwards only.

How can I simulate it in php-5.5?
It is not really necessary to pack all 64 bits.

My try does not seem to be correct (on Win7 64bit):

```
pack('J', $val) === pack('N', 0) . pack('N', $val)
```

Comment: By saying *"It is not really necessary to pack all 64 bits."*, do you mean that you're actually packing a 32-bit value?

Comment: And also, what is the value that you're trying to do this with? It does work for positive integers ...

Comment: @narf yes sorry, it seems to work that way. The error was on another place in code. But btw (how) is it possible to save all 64 bits?

Comment: it is mainly to let the code be executed on dev (windows) w/o altering (esp. unittests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a smarter way to do this, but this works:

```
// base_convert() will treat your value as a string here,
// converting it from decimal to hexadecimal
$hexStringValue = base_convert($your64bitInteger, 10, 16);

// Pad with zeros to the left, until pack()'s output length is matched
$hexStringValue = str_pad($hexStringValue, 16, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

// Convert to binary
$packed64bitInteger = hex2bin($hexStringValue);
```

---

I must note however, [PHP 5.5 reached EOL in July 2016](https://secure.php.net/eol.php) and you should be upgrading to at least version 5.6 anyway.

Comment: Had written `bin2hex()` instead of `hex2bin()` initially ... fixed that.