# pack format "Q" on PHP 5.5 / 32 bit machines

Tags: php, integer, bit-manipulation, backwards-compatibility

I would like to implement something as described here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101153 in PHP. So far the following seems to be working:

*encode*

```
return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(pack('Q', $int64)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
```

*decode*

```
$bytes = base64_decode(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'));
return unpack('Q', $bytes)[1];
```

Unfortunately this only works on 64bit systems and PHP5.6.3+ where the "Q" format of pack/unpack was introduced.

What possibilities do I have to implement the same function that would work the same on php5.5 64 & 32 bit?

Comment: 'Q' being machine-dependant byte order is trickier, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41060369/468027

Comment: thanks @Narf - I think I might have reached a jackpot in combination with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#106546, happy for you to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not really comfortable with posting incomplete answers. Plus, you're doing something that's very specific and this is unlikely to help other users ... Everyone should be encouraged to upgrade their PHP versions anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Narf, using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41060369/468027 and replacing `base_convert` with either: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#106546 or http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#109660 solved the issue for me.